# Import Excel 97-2003 worksheets to active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The following code imports Excel files (".xlsx") in the defined path into my active workbook.

```
Sub GetSheets1()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim fPath As String, fName As String
    Dim destWB As Workbook, currentWB As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook
    fPath = "C:\Users\francisca.cambra\Dropbox\Faculdade\Thesis\MS-Project\MacroTest\"
    fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While fName <> ""
        Set currentWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fPath & fName, ReadOnly:=True)
        For i = 1 To currentWB.Sheets.Count
            currentWB.Sheets(i).Copy After:=destWB.Sheets(destWB.Sheets.Count)
        Next i
        currentWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        fName = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```

For Excel 97-2003 files, when I change the `fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xlsx")` to `fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls")`, the workbook becomes empty, without the macros and data.

The macro imports the Excel 97-2003 files when I comment the `currentWB.Close SaveChanges:=False` line, and it copies twice the first Excel workbook it gets. I think the currentWB is once the ActiveBook, and when the macro is run, the ActiveBook is closed, but I don't know why since the ActiveBook has a different extension from the others, so the loop shouldn't store the ActiveBook.

Comment: Most odd. I can't replicate this error. Code works fine for me. Is it possible that one of your .xls files contains macros that are interfering?

Comment: Those files don't have any macros... I don't really know what's wrong.

Comment: Are you able to debug and step through your code and discover when it fails? Try executing it just with a single .xls file, perhaps with a single worksheet. Do the workbooks contain any other sheet types than just Worksheet? You could also try manually copying some sheets to see if an error arises.

Comment: Thanks @AndyG, I already solved the problem, after a lot of effort...

Answer (score 0):

Solved  :)

```
Sub GetSheets1()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim fPath As String, fName As String
    Dim destWB As Workbook, currentWB As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook
    fPath = "C:\Users\francisca.cambra\Dropbox\Faculdade\Thesis\MS-Project\MacroTest\"
    fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls")
    Do While fName <> ""
        If fName <> "Blank.xlsm.xlsm" Then
            Set currentWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fPath & fName)
            For i = 1 To currentWB.Sheets.Count
                currentWB.Sheets(i).Copy After:=destWB.Sheets(destWB.Sheets.Count)
            Next i
            currentWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        fName = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```